mt command with mkpartition operation on HP LTO-6 drive not working properly
I'm trying to create a second partition on LTO-5 and LTO-6 cartridges using the command mt -f /dev/nst0 mkpartition 100 on a HP LTO-6 drive but it fails with /dev/nst0: Input/output error.
I also tried to reduce the value to 10 (so it should make a 10 MB partition) but I get the same error.
The only value who worked is 1 (2 and above always fail). I can then change to the partition 1 with mt -f /dev/nst0 setpartition 1
I can also restore the cartridge to a one partition only format with mt -f /dev/nst0 mkpartition 0.
I tried to find what could be the problem but there's very few people talking about that command and no one is having the same problem as me it seems. All the various manuals for mt say the same thing and what I typed should work.
Can someone help me make that command create a 100 MB partition (or any other size I'd chose) as it's supposed to do? thanks in advance.
I'm on Kubuntu 22.04.
